# Unexecuted code overrides local variable

Tags: ruby, local-variables, ambiguity

Given code:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize
    @bar = "abc"
    if false
      bar = "123"
    end
    p bar
  end
end

Foo.new
```

The result is

```
nil
```

Why does `p bar` in `initialize` print `nil` instead of `abc`?

Comment: because `bar` is not the same as `@bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize
    p "instance methods defined in Foo: #{self.methods(false)}"  
    @bar = "abc"
    p "defined? @bar: #{defined? @bar}"
    p "bar: #{bar}"
    p "defined? bar: #{defined? bar}"
    if false
      bar = "123"
    end
    p "defined? bar, 2nd time: #{defined? bar}"
    p "bar.nil? = #{bar.nil?}"
    p "self.bar = #{self.bar}"
    p "instance methods defined in Foo: #{self.class.instance_methods(false)}"  
  end
end

Foo.new
"instance methods defined in Foo: [:bar]"
"defined? @bar: instance-variable"
"bar: abc"
"defined? bar: method"
"defined? bar, 2nd time: local-variable"
"bar.nil? = true"
"self.bar = abc"
"instance methods defined in Foo: [:bar]"
```

The lines:

```
"defined? @bar: instance-variable"
"defined? bar: method"
```

show that `@bar` is an instance variable and `bar` is an instance method, namely the getter method for `@bar` created by `attr_reader :bar`. Before

```
if false
  bar = "123"
end
```

is evaluated, Ruby peers into the `if` clause. There she sees `bar = "123"`. If invoked, this would assign the value `"123"`to an uninitialized local variable `bar`.

`bar=` cannot be an instance method (e.g., a setter for `@bar`) because any method whose name ends with an equals sign must be invoked on an *explicit receiver*. (It works that way to allow coders to use local variables that have the same names as instance variables, minus the leading `@`.)

What is an "explicit" receiver? If `Foo` had a public instance method `buz`, you could write:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.buz
```

`foo` is an explicit receiver for the method `buz`. To invoke `buz` from within one of `Foo`'s instance methods, you could use an explicit receiver:

```
self.buz
```

or just write:

```
buz
```

in which case `self` is the *implicit* receiver.

As `bar=` can only be written with an explicit receiver, we would have write:

```
attr_writer :bar
...
self.bar = "123"
```

to invoke `@bar`'s setter.

Where were we? Ah, we just concluded that:

```
if false
  bar = "123"
end
```

would assign a value to the local variable `bar` if the `if` clause were executed, regardless of whether there exists a method `Foo#bar=`.

Because `false` is, well, `false`, the contents of the `if` clause are not executed, so the value of `bar` is not changed from `nil`.

The important thing is that the local variable `bar` and the instance variable `@bar` are just as different from each other as are `night` and `@day`. We can easily show that as follows:

```
a  = 'cat'
@a = 'dog'
a  #=> "cat" 
a  = 'pig'
@a #=> "dog"
```

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to miss the point. Note that the code has `attr_reader :bar`. The issue is not about conflict between `bar` and `@bar`; it is about between the local variable `bar` and the method `bar`.

Comment: @sawa, darn, I missed the accessor complelely. Thanks for letting me know. Fixed, I think.

Comment: I changed `attr_reader` to `attr_accessor` and ran your code. It still gives exactly the same output (`bar` is `nil`, not `123`).

Comment: @Anand, I corrected another mistake I made. :-) Is it now clear?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. There might be one other subtlety:   If we remove the class, etc., and call: `if false; bar = 12; end; p bar;`, it prints `nil`, but just saying `p bar` raises a `NameError`. I suspect that during compilation, in the first case, a variable for `bar` is created on the internal stack and initialized to `nil` since the token is identified to be a local variable. This variable remains on the stack beyond the if statement at runtime, hence `nil` is printed. In the second case, since bar is an argument to `p`,  no variable is created on the stack, and hence the error.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but why Ruby chooses to initialize local variables within conditional clauses (to `nil`), regardless of whether the variables are referenced, I can only guess.

Comment: I could venture a guess - the compiler identifies all local variables and initializes them to nil on the stack. Without evaluating the expressions, they have no way of saying whether or not it is in a conditional clause, or whether the clause will actually fire at runtime. Later, at runtime, it evaluates expressions like the false condition here, and skips the assignment. But now it is too late (and probably inefficient) to inspect the stack and remove the variables. So, the variable remains on the stack. I suspect most dynamic languages would suffer from similar problems.

Comment: Thanks! @CarySwoveland for the thorough explanation. The way you debug the code well explained what happens here. To sum up your answer: 1. `@bar` is an instance variable, and it always is; 2. `bar` could be `local variable` or `method`. In this case, due to `attr_reader :bar`, `bar` became `method` first; then due to `bar = "123"` (even if it's not executed), `bar` became `local variable` and value is `nil`. 3. Implicit call `p bar` is calling `bar` as `local variable`. If want to call `bar` as method, use explicit call `p self.bar`, which is equivalent to `p @bar`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the line

```
bar = "123"
```

is parsed, it initializes the local variable `bar` to `nil` within the scope even if it is not executed. This behavior (characteristic of local variables) is due to local variables taking lexical scope; their scope must be determined without executing the code. And when a token is ambiguous between a local variable and a method, it is interpreted as a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

`p bar` would not return `"abc"` because `bar` and `@bar` are different. `@bar` is an instance variable, but when you call it without prefix @, ruby searches for a local variable.

Normally in ruby, instance variables and global variables when not defined, return `nil`. But local variables throw error when **undefined**. But in your case, you have tried to initialize the variable, even if it is never initialized due to the `if false`, it still has been parsed, and that is enough for the ruby interpreter to return `nil`.

This has been explained clearly in [this link](http://code-worrier.com/blog/all-your-vars/)